# Where does Spark store its profiling results?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, bigdata

One can view profiling statistics of a Spark program through a browser on port 4040. However, the cluster I am running it on, doesn't have a browser and also I'm not the admin. Is this information also logged in some file, so that I can make my own tool to visualize the statistics by reading such file?

Note that I run Spark over YARN. But sometimes I also run using local standalone mode. So any answer related to that is also appreciated.

Comment: Standalone Spark cluster? Or YARN / Mesos?

Comment: I am running Spark over YARN.

Comment: You may be able to access the ResourceManager application history if using YARN. Obviously, doesn't give the same metrics as the Spark UI, though. Why does it matter if the Spark computer doesn't have a browser, though? Use that computer's IP/hostname from another computer on the network

Comment: I tried to use that, but it tries to keep on connecting.